# Android app throws error only on real device

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

The application translates from binary code into other number systems.

On the emulator everything works but when you press the button in the application, then everything closes and gives an error that points to this line (58)

```
numArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(numArrF[i]);
```

I think this is a problem with library versions. Or they are completely absent on a real device. I don't understand the problem.

Here is the code of Main Activity:

```java
package com.example.myct;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
import static java.util.Arrays.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void onMyButtonClick(View view) {
        Spinner mySpinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String spinNum1 = mySpinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Spinner mySpinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        String spinNum2 = mySpinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        EditText number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
        String eNum = number.getText().toString();

        TextView Field = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Field);
        String fieldI = Field.getText().toString();
        Field.setText("");

        if (spinNum1.equals("2")) {

            if (spinNum2.equals("2")) {
                Field.setText(eNum);
            }

            //преобразование строки eNum в int массив
            String[] numArrF = eNum.split("");
            int numArr[] = new int[numArrF.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < numArrF.length; i++) {
                numArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(numArrF[i]);
            }
            //////////////////

            boolean solve = true;
            //test null and one
            for(int i = numArr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
                if (numArr[i] != 1 && numArr[i] != 0) {
                    solve = false;
                    Log.d("solve", "false");
                }
            }
            //////////////////

            //если в массиве все элементы равны только нулю и еденице
            if (solve) {


                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                if (spinNum2.equals("2")) {
                    Field.setText(eNum);
                }
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                else if (spinNum2.equals("8")){

                    String[] arrStr = eNum.replaceAll("(.{3})","$1 ").split(" ");

                    for (int i = arrStr.length-1; i < arrStr.length; i++){
                        if (arrStr[i].length() < 3){
                            arrStr[i] = "0" + arrStr[i];
                        }
                    }

                    for(int i = 0;  i < arrStr.length; i++ ){

                        String str = arrStr[i];


                        if(str.equals("000")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "0";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("000 = 0");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 000 = 0");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("001")){

                            arrStr[i] = "1";
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("001 = 1");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 001 = 1");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("010")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "2";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("010 = 2");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 010 = 2");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("011")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "3";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("011 = 3");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 011 = 3");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("100")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "4";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("100 = 4");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 100 = 4");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("101")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "5";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("101 = 5");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 101 = 5");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("110")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "6";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("110 = 6");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 110 = 6");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("111")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "7";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("111 = 7");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 111 = 7");}
                        }

                    }

                }
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                else if (spinNum2.equals("10")) {

                    int sum = 0;

                    int[] comp = new int[numArr.length];

                    int a = 0;
                    for (int i = numArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        //записываем в ячейку что она равна самой себе умноженной на 2 в степени i
                        int camper = (int) Math.pow(2, a);

                        comp[i] = numArr[i] * camper;

                        //сумма всех ячеек
                        sum += comp[i];

                        if (i == 0) {
                            String otherA = Field.getText().toString();
                            Field.setText(otherA + numArr[i] + " * 2^" + a + " = " + sum);
                        } else {
                            String otherB = Field.getText().toString();
                            Field.setText(otherB + numArr[i] + " * 2^" + a + " + ");
                        }
                        a++;
                    }
                }
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                else if (spinNum2.equals("16")){

                    String[] arrStr = eNum.replaceAll("(.{4})","$1 ").split(" ");

                    for (int i = arrStr.length-1; i < arrStr.length; i++){
                        if (arrStr[i].length() < 4){
                            arrStr[i] = "0" + arrStr[i];
                        }
                    }

                    for(int i = 0;  i < arrStr.length; i++ ){

                        String str = arrStr[i];


                        if(str.equals("0000")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "0";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("0000 = 0");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 0000 = 0");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("0001")){

                            arrStr[i] = "1";
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("0001 = 1");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 0001 = 1");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("0010")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "2";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("0010 = 2");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 0010 = 2");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("0011")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "3";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("0011 = 3");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 0011 = 3");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("0100")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "4";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("0100 = 4");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 0100 = 4");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("0101")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "5";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("0101 = 5");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 0101 = 5");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("0110")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "6";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("0110 = 6");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 0110 = 6");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("0111")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "7";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("0111 = 7");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 0111 = 7");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("1000")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "8";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("1000 = 8");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 1000 = 8");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("1001")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "9";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("1001 = 9");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 1001 = 9");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("1010")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "A";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("1010 = A");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 1010 = A");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("1011")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "B";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("1011 = B");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 1011 = B");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("1100")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "C";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("1100 = C");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 1100 = C");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("1101")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "D";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("1101 = D");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 1101 = D");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("1110")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "E";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("1110 = E");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 1110 = E");}
                        }
                        else if(str.equals("1111")){
                            String other = Field.getText().toString();
                            arrStr[i] = "F";
                            if(i == 0){
                                Field.setText("1111 = F");
                            }
                            else {Field.setText(other+", 1111 = F");}
                        }

                    }
                }
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            }
            else {
                Field.setText("Dont binary.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your logcat?

Comment: error code?0000

Comment: yes what is your logcat showing? post here

Comment: Yes, all of the text in the "logcat" console. You'll see a tab at the bottom of Android Studio.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/13gVvCia9ZRwJBTl_SY1UXjebkEwPcQ3HdFHuwnbZMoE/edit?usp=sharing
@splrs

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/13gVvCia9ZRwJBTl_SY1UXjebkEwPcQ3HdFHuwnbZMoE/edit?usp=sharing
@UsamaAltaf

Comment: Add the error to your question, not a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

The error message is clear that you're trying to convert an empty string to an integer. So what you need to do is to check whether the string is empty or not before converting it into the integer.

```
String[] numArrF = enum.split("");
int numArr[] = new int[numArrF.length];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < numArrF.length; i++) {
    if(!numArrF[i].isEmpty()) numArr[j++] = Integer.parseInt(numArrF[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should catch `NumberFormatException`, because there your try to parse empty line into number.

```java
try {
    numArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(numArrF[i]);
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    numArr[i] = defaultValue; //Use default value if parsing failed
}
```

Comment: where do I need to replace. I do not quite understand you.

Comment: At line 58, where the error happens